# How to install all dependecies while using YUM in centos

Tags: mongodb, centos, dependencies, installation, yum

I am trying to install mongo db and to do that stdlibc++ dependencies are needed which are hard to get. so i need a command which can install all the needed dependencies by itself. Please help me on this.

uname -a

gives

Linux sscent-03.local 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 15 04:27:16 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

and the error is like,

Error: Package: libcddb-1.3.2-12.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)

```
       Requires: libcdio.so.15(CDIO_15)(64bit)
```

Error: libcmpiCppImpl0 conflicts with 2:tog-pegasus-2.12.0-3.el6_4.x86_64

Error: Package: libcddb-1.3.2-12.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)

```
       Requires: libcdio.so.15()(64bit)
```

** Found 2 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:

libstdc++-4.8.3-9.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with libstdc++-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64

libstdc++-4.8.3-9.el7.x86_64 has missing requires of libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)

Thanks,
Manirathinam M.

Comment: What OS are you running? What arch? Edit your original post and include output of `uname -a`. Typically yum installs all the dependencies, in your case try 'yum install libstdc++'. PS: This question should be asked on serverfault.com

Comment: Yeah i will post it there too. but i updated the error also @Deeh

Comment: atleast help me in a way that i can find the dependent rpm's. Its hard for even finding it.

Comment: Your problem is that you have Centos6 `2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64` and installing packages for Centos7 `libstdc++-4.8.3-9.el7.x86_64`

Comment: So you are saying that i cannot install those packages(or dependencies) in my os now ?
Actually i get these errors while i am trying 'yum install mongodb' . So only am trying to install those dependent packages .

Comment: What i'm saying is that you're installing wrong packages that are meant for a different OS and probably have wrong repo configured on your box. Whats the output of `yum repolist` and output of `rpm -qa | grep -i epel`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78929/discussion-between-mani-and-deeh).